# Задан файл целых чисел. Указать диапазон, в котором находятся его элементы

Tags: java

Смог сделать данную задачу не считывая данные с файла, а случайными числами.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    static int n = 20;
    static int [] mas = new int[n];
    static Scanner scn;

    public static int minElement()
    {
        int min = mas[0];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            if(min > mas[i])
               min = mas[i];
        }

        return min;
    }
    public static int maxElement()
    {
        int max = mas[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (max < mas[i])
                max = mas[i];
        }
        return max;
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            mas[i] = Math.abs(random.nextInt(100));
        System.out.println("Элементы массива :");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            System.out.print(mas[i] + " ");     

        System.out.println("\nМинимальеый элемент массива : " + minElement());
        System.out.println("Максимальный элемент массива : " + maxElement());
        System.out.println("Диапазон чисел в данном массиве от " + minElement() + " до " + maxElement());
    }
}
```

Что нужно изменить/добавить для ввода данных с файла?

Answer (score 1):

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("filename.txt))) {
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        mas[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Etc...